# How to use syn v2 to parse an attritube like this: `#[attr("a", "b", "c")]`?

Tags: rust, syn

In `syn` v1, there is `NestedMeta` which is very convenient for parsing nested meta. But since `syn` v2, it's somehow been removed.

For example,

```rust
trait Hello {
    fn hello();
}

#[derive(Hello)]
#[hello("world1", "world2")]
struct A;

fn main() {
    A::hello();
}
```

I want the code above to print `Hello world1, world2!` on the screen. My proc-macro can be implemented using `syn` v1 like below

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{DeriveInput, Meta};

#[proc_macro_derive(Hello, attributes(hello))]
pub fn hello_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let name = &ast.ident;

    let mut target: Vec<String> = vec![];

    for attr in ast.attrs {
        if let Some(attr_meta_name) = attr.path.get_ident() {
            if attr_meta_name == "hello" {
                let attr_meta = attr.parse_meta().unwrap();

                match attr_meta {
                    Meta::List(list) => {
                        for p in list.nested {
                            match p {
                                NestedMeta::Lit(lit) => match lit {
                                    Lit::Str(lit) => {
                                        target.push(lit.value());
                                    },
                                    _ => {
                                        panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute.")
                                    },
                                },
                                NestedMeta::Meta(_) => {
                                    panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute.")
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    _ => panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute."),
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if target.is_empty() {
        panic!("The `hello` attribute must be used to set at least one target.");
    }

    let target = target.join(", ");

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl Hello for #name {
            fn hello() {
                println!("Hello {}.", #target);
            }
        }
    };

    expanded.into()
}
```

But when I am trying to re-implement it with `syn` v2, I stuck on the `parse_nested_meta` method which seems to reject the literals.

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{DeriveInput, Meta};

#[proc_macro_derive(Hello, attributes(hello))]
pub fn hello_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let name = &ast.ident;

    let mut target: Vec<String> = vec![];

    for attr in ast.attrs {
        if let Some(attr_meta_name) = attr.path().get_ident() {
            if attr_meta_name == "hello" {
                let attr_meta = attr.meta;

                match attr_meta {
                    Meta::List(list) => {
                        list.parse_nested_meta(|meta| {
                            // I don't know how to handle this
                            Ok(())
                        })
                        .unwrap();
                    },
                    _ => panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute."),
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if target.is_empty() {
        panic!("The `hello` attribute must be used to set at least one target.");
    }

    let target = target.join(", ");

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl Hello for #name {
            fn hello() {
                println!("Hello {}.", #target);
            }
        }
    };

    expanded.into()
}
```

How to use `syn` v2 to parse the attribute?

Comment: What about [`MetaList`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.MetaList.html)?

Comment: @PitaJ Are you suggesting that I use other method instead of `parse_nested_meta`?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about syn. It would help it you would post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have already given my whole code. You can just paste and run it.

Answer (score 2):

with syn v2 things have changed a little bit, so in your code:

```rust
    for attr in ast.attrs {
        if let Some(attr_meta_name) = attr.path().get_ident() {
            if attr_meta_name == "hello" {
                let attr_meta = attr.meta;

                match attr_meta {
                    Meta::List(list) => {
                        list.parse_nested_meta(|meta| {
                            // I don't know how to handle this
                            Ok(())
                        })
                        .unwrap();
                    },
                    _ => panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute."),
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you would want do use the `Punctuated::parse_terminated()` function like this:

```rust
list.parse_args_with(Punctuated::<LitStr, Token![,]>::parse_terminated)
```

Putting the things together your for loop would then look like this:

```rust
    for attr in ast.attrs {
        match &attr {
            Meta::List(list) if list.path.is_ident("hello") => {
                list.parse_args_with(Punctuated::<LitStr, Token![,]>::parse_terminated)
                    .map_err(|_| {
                        // returning a specific syn::Error to teach the right usage of your macro 
                        syn::Error::new(
                            list.span(),
                            // this indoc macro is just convenience and requires the indoc crate but can be done without it
                            indoc! {r#"
                                The `hello` attribute expects string literals to be comma separated

                                = help: use `#[hello("world1", "world2")]`
                            "#}
                        )
                    })?;
            }
            meta => {
                // returning a syn::Error would help with the compiler diagnostics and guide your macro users to get it right
                return Err(syn::Error::new(
                    meta.span(),
                    indoc! {r#"
                        The `hello` attribute is the only supported argument

                        = help: use `#[hello("world1")]`
                    "#})
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Notes:

- the `indoc` crate and macro is just nice to have, but really neat!
- the compiler error messages are also nice to have, but greatly improves the usability of your macro
- there is a very [nice blog post from ferrous systems on all the things to consider for proc macro development](https://ferrous-systems.com/blog/testing-proc-macros/#diagnostics)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are no other built-in struct which is implemented the `Parse` trait can do that. So we have to create one on our own.

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{
    parse::{Parse, ParseStream},
    DeriveInput, LitStr, Meta, Token,
};

struct MyParser {
    v: Vec<String>,
}

impl Parse for MyParser {
    #[inline]
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self, syn::Error> {
        let mut v: Vec<String> = vec![];

        loop {
            if input.is_empty() {
                break;
            }

            v.push(input.parse::<LitStr>()?.value());

            if input.is_empty() {
                break;
            }

            input.parse::<Token!(,)>()?;
        }

        Ok(MyParser {
            v,
        })
    }
}

#[proc_macro_derive(Hello, attributes(hello))]
pub fn hello_world_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let name = &ast.ident;

    let mut target: Vec<String> = vec![];

    for attr in ast.attrs {
        if attr.path().is_ident("hello") {
            match attr.meta {
                Meta::List(list) => {
                    let parsed: MyParser = list.parse_args().unwrap();

                    target.extend_from_slice(&parsed.v);
                },
                _ => panic!("Incorrect format for using the `hello` attribute."),
            }
        }
    }

    if target.is_empty() {
        panic!("The `hello` attribute must be used to set at least one target.");
    }

    let target = target.join(", ");

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl Hello for #name {
            fn hello() {
                println!("Hello {}.", #target);
            }
        }
    };

    expanded.into()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Hello, attributes(hello))]
pub fn hello_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let name = &ast.ident;

    let mut target: Vec<String> = vec![];

    for attr in ast.attrs {
        match &attr.meta {
            syn::Meta::List(list) if attr.path().is_ident("hello") => target.extend(
                list.parse_args::<Greetings>()
                    .unwrap()
                    .0
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|lit| lit.value()),
            ),
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    if target.is_empty() {
        panic!("The `hello` attribute must be used to set at least one target.");
    }

    let target = target.join(", ");

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl Hello for #name {
            fn hello() {
                println!("Hello {}.", #target);
            }
        }
    };

    expanded.into()
}

struct Greetings(Punctuated<LitStr, Token![,]>);

impl syn::parse::Parse for Greetings {
    fn parse(input: syn::parse::ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self(Punctuated::<LitStr, Token![,]>::parse_terminated(
            input,
        )?))
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).